# Permission to create GPOs

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, powershell

Is the sole reason of the Group Policy Creator Owner group just to dish out permissions to other users to create (and then modify only their own) GPOs in the domain?

Is there another way to do this via Powershell, or is this group the only way? i.e. just dish out the permissions without being a member of the said group.

There is a PS cmdlet such like: `Set-GPPermission` for example etc. Although according to their technet on the article it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781991%28v=WS.10%29.aspx):

> The ability to create GPOs in a domain is a permission that is managed
>   on a per-domain basis. By default, only Domain Administrators,
>   Enterprise Administrators, Group Policy Creator Owners, and SYSTEM can
>   create new Group Policy objects. If the domain administrator wants a
>   non-administrator or non-administrative group to be able to create
>   GPOs, that user or group can be added to the Group Policy Creator
>   Owners security group. Alternatively, you can use the Delegation tab
>   on the Group Policy Objects container in GPMC to delegate creation of
>   GPOs.

So yes, if you want someone to create GPOs, either put them in the GP Creator Owners group, or delegate the permission to create and link GPOs to another group of your choosing.

[Set-GPPermission](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967451%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) does not really concern you. That Cmdlet is about targeting so you can prevent a GPO from applying to certain principals even though their location in the OU structure would otherwise fall under the scope of that GPO.